# Suddenly unable to open hyperlinks in Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

I'm using Word 2016. When I click on hyperlinks in documents I'm editing, I get the message, "Your organization's policies are preventing us from completing this action for you" and I'm then advised to contact my help desk. I am not part of an organization and unfortunately, do not have a help desk.
This is a new problem--hyperlinks worked fine last week.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an article on this.  It apparently is related to your Internet Explorer settings.  Microsoft provides a few approaches to tackle this issue.  Let us know if any of them work. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/hyperlinks-not-working-in-outlook